# Push Notifications in Android using Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently developing an app where users create posts that are stored on a server.  When another user shows interest in a post by clicking a button, I want to notify the author of the post using push notifications.  I have already set up the data storage using cloud endpoints with Google App Engine.   Is there anyway I can use these endpoints to implement push notifications?  If not is there another easy way to implement push notifications given my current setup?  I have already read about Google Cloud Messaging on the developers page but was somewhat confused.  I have kept track of the registration id's but I don't really know where to go from there.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072114/google-app-engine-and-android-oauth-c2dm-or-cloud-messaging?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

You can use the HTTP interface to the GCM servers as described in this
[Android developers page](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html).

The easiest way to do it is by downloading the Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library using the Android SDK Manager, which will give you a jar that handles all the complexity of setting up the requests and responses to GCM.

Towards the bottom of that page, there is a sample Java application for push notifications on App Engine which you can use to get familiar with sending push notifications and then adapt to your needs.